# Acunetix SQL injection Try

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security

I've got a license for Acunetix OVS (online scanner), and in the results I got tons of SQL Injection Vulnerabilities for this WebSite (MS ASP.Net v4 site)..

I need to test that the finding is not a False Positive, so I take one for example, Acunetix says a SQL Injection has been found in http://URL/SomePage.aspx
Parameter: __LASTFOCUS

Attack details
POST (multipart) input __LASTFOCUS was set to 1ACUSTART'"1BJuNACUEND
Error message found:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:

It actually means, that given the Exception, it affects directly to an SQL execution..

So I go ahead and open up Postman Interceptor execute a POST request using this page, and then in Postman I get the Request in the history..

All headers, cookies and Body POST parameters are there including the "__LASTFOCUS" parameter..

No matter what I enter (even the value Acunetix said it sent) I don't get no SQL Error Message.. The page answers fine, I've tried with different POST scenarios all of them works great..

Is there a way I can actually test with intention that it fails with SQL Exception so I can prove the client that the vulnerability is real and not a False Positive?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What would be best to do here is to open up profiler, start it and then send the request. From here you can see the SQL that is executed on the server and therefore can test if indeed it is vulnerable. It might be that the application logic is changing the behavior. For example, depending on a variable it might fall into different SQL. I'm not familiar with postman but I highly recommend fiddler, you can capture a request and duplicate it exactly making it highly useful in this scenario.

Comment: What response do you receive? Was the vulnerability detected in a logged in context (as though you are a logged in user)?